# OSXFuse mounted directory ownership error with automount SSHFS

Tags: mount, fstab, sshfs, macos-sierra, fuse

I am running on macOS Sierra and I am trying to configure auto-mount of external server's directory via SSHFS and osxfuse. However, every time the disk is being mounted, it is owned by `root` and normal user does not seem to have access. I have downloaded the latest stable release of `osxfuse` version 3.5.5.

I have been looking for a solution for couple of hours and none of them did not help. I have already tried setting the `allow_other` to 1 via

```
sysctl -w osxfuse.tunables.allow_other=1
```

However it returns an error

```
sysctl: unknown oid 'osxfuse.tunables.allow_other'
```

**Note:** when I try to simply mount the disk via

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=/path/to/key user@host:/path/to/external /path/to/local
```

This works as expected. The problem occurs when I am trying to configure auto-mount of the same directory. I have also found a tutorial which instructs to create a `plist` which loads osxfuse, however it uses a path `/Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/Support/load_osxfusefs`, whereas all I can find is `/Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/Contents/Resources/load_osxfuse`. And even if I replace those values, nothing changes.

Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

In current versions of OSXFuse and mac OS, the name to use for sysctl seems to actually be "vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.allow_other".
So the command would be:

```
sysctl -w vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.allow_other=1
```

Same with "vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.admin_group", which might also be of interest to you. It allows you to give allow_other rights only to a specific group, which offers more security. The [wiki on this](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options#allow_other) also uses the wrong commands, but the info is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using a mac for a while, so I hope this will help:

I created the place to mount the volume in /media/my_mountfile, and change the permissions for it to be available for every user `chmod 777 /media/my_mountfile`. 
Then I added `sshfs` command directly into my `~/.bashrs` or `~/.bashprofile`.
To achieve this, you must exchange rsa keys between both computers in order not to need a password when connecting with `ssh` or `sshfs`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but you just need to add an option to sshfs defer_permissions.
Mine worked straight out.